# how to copy mailitem in outlook c#

Tags: c#, outlook, mailitem

I am writing an outlook add-in,
and I need when receiving an email, it goes to default inbox folder as normal, but it make a copy of that incoming email and put it into another folder(say Junk folder as example).
but I encounter the exception "Cannot move the items." all the time when i move the copy of the email. any ideas?

```
private void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
 {


    Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
    (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);


    // the incoming email
    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
    //make a copy of it but error occurs
    Outlook.MailItem cItem = mail.copy();
    //
    cItem = (Outlook.MailItem)cItem.Move((Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
    (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the ItemAdd event handler. Try to store the item's entry id in a variable or a list and start a timer (use the one from the Forms namespace). When the time fires, you will be out of the event handler and should be able to call MailItem.Move.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, do you mean I can not move an mailitem in the ItemAdd event handler? actually, I want to store the emails in different folders according to the email subject, so how do I do this?

Comment: The item being passed by Outlook to the event handler will become invalid if you call Move. You can just move the logic to the timer event handler.

Comment: So how can I make a copy of that email and store the original one and the copy into different folders? Is the timer the only way of doing this? thanks

Comment: Copy (unlike Move) should be fine: call MailItem.Copy, then call MailItem.Move on the returned item.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I tried MailItem.Copy, but I always get a exception saying "the operation failed", no idea why it happens

Comment: Have tried copy, but it always give an exception saying "the operation failed"... no idea why this happens

Comment: this helps a bit, but I also found there can be multiple item_add event fired sometimes, it can be a little bit more tricky, thanks for help!

Comment: That's why you need to have a list of entry ids instead of a string variable that holds a single entry id.

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by entry ids? how entry ids effect this? Sigh, can't MS just make something simple...

Comment: I meant if you took my advise and stored the entry id in a list to be processed when the time event fires. This way you can handle ItemAdd event firing multiple times before you get a chance to process them.